# Commerce Stripe Authorize Only - Capture partial amount in Craft admin panel

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, stripe

It doesn't look possible but can you capture partial amounts using the Craft admin panel?  E.g. Authorize $1000, then capture $700.

Also, when performing Captures in the Stripe panel, these transactions do not show in Craft in the Order Transactions box.  This looks like a bug to me.

Last, if we can't perform partial captures in Craft and need to do it in Stripe, how can we mark Orders as paid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Commerce 2.0.0-beta.7,  partial capture is not yet supported. Look out for it in the next release.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you also let me know how can we mark manually Orders as paid?

Comment: marked as paid is a dynamic status based on whether the amountPaid is greater than or equal to the totalPrice